# Building v2-compatible Singularity images with the version 3 of Singularity

Tags: singularity-container

When I  create `.sif` images from a sandbox folder with the Singularity version  3.2.0, I receive the following error when running on another  machine with Singularity version 2.6:

```
ERROR  : Unknown image format/type: container_name.sif
ABORT  : Retval = 255
```

So the question is:

Is there  a way to build version2-compatible Singularity images with version 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image format changed significantly between v3 and v2 and are not backwards compatible.